# Trying to download Import Cost extension on Code:OSS

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to download the Import Cost extension on Code:OSS but every time I and search for it or run `ext install wix.vscode-import-cost` it doesn't show!
It seems like VScode and Code:OSS don't share the same repository! What can I do to change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here!
https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/blob/master/DOCS.md#extensions-marketplace
and if you're using Arch Linux, the [code-marketplace](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/code-marketplace/) package in AUR will patch the porduct.json file without you having to edit it manually.